# java.lang.AssertionError: Incorrect result expected [1019.1690418083019] but found [755.0]

Tags: java

I wrote a piece of code to check the maximum value in an array and return the maximum after checking all the values. I keep getting an error when I run my code. Any input?

```
// Initialize maximum to the first value
double maximum = measurements[0];
// Now go through the rest of the array
for (double i = 0; i < measurements.length; i++) {
    if (i > maximum) {
        maximum = i;
    }
}
// At each step, compare the value to our current maximum
// If it's greater, replace maximum
System.out.println(maximum);
```

java.lang.AssertionError: Incorrect result expected [1019.1690418083019] but found [755.0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change

```
if (i > maximum) {
        maximum = i;
    }
```

to

```
if (measurements[i] > maximum) {
        maximum = measurements[i];
    }
```

Actually the issue is that you are comparing the `i` with `maximum` instead of `measurements[i]`

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the value of maximum to be your iterator. You should probably do

> maximum = measurements[i]

Speaking of iterators, is there any reason why you're using a double for your iterator? I suggest you use int.

Edit: I also found an issue with your if statement.

> if (i > maximum) {

This is comparing your iterator value to the current maximum value. You should do something like

> measurements[i] > maximum

To check the actual values within your array.